# How do you say "I've been serving my master my whole life." in Latin?

Tags: syntax

How do you say "*I've been serving my master my whole life.*"  in Latin? I think it is "*Totam vitam servo dominum meum.*" (literal translation of Croatian "*Cijeli život služim gospodara mog.*"), but I am not sure whether "*tota vita*" (*whole life*) goes in ablative or the accusative.

Comment: *Servo* is from *servare*, not *servire*.

Comment: @Cairnarvon What's the difference between "servare" and "servire"?

Comment: @FlatAssembler They're different verbs? *Servare* means 'to protect' or 'to maintain' (cf. English *preserve*, *conserve*), *servire* is 'to serve'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, use the accusative for duration, but using *per* is a better way to express this. Take for example this passage from Livy:

> hic mos, quem per omnem vitam servabat...

> This custom, which he kept throughout his life...

The passage actually brings up the other issue, as Cairnarvon points out in the comments, which is that you need to use *servio*, not *servo*. The former means "to serve," while the latter means "to save, keep, preserve, or protect."

Both *totam* and *omnem* are attested, and usually *vitam* comes second.

And lastly, as cnread points out, *servire* takes a dative.

Put together, you get:

> Per omnem vitam domino meo servio.